# bash: source (".") completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have my own scripts folder somewhere in home. It's in PATH.

In bash, when I start writing and hit `TAB`, the scripts get completed nicely.

But when I start with `.` (source), completion with `TAB` doesn't work.

Is it possible to get completion after `.` too? Thanks

Comment: `.` reads from a file, not from a command. If you want tab completion, you'll get it when you try to supply a valid argument, like `/home/myuser/myscript.sh`, not just `myscript.sh` unless `~` is your current working directory.

Comment: Woah. I was just posting an answer quoting the `help .`, but then I noticed this: `The entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.` I then did a test with `. pydoc`. It had a syntax error, but it was indeed trying to source the file. My answer, despite the sense it makes, is wrong :/ It's true that giving it a file path will get you tab completion, but now I'm not sure why it won't give you tab completion from PATH.

Comment: by "completion" are you asking only about TAB filename completion, or having the scripts be found in $PATH?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I have a script `setEnv.sh` in `/home/me/work/scripts`. If I am in `/home/me`, and I have `/home/me/work/scripts` in `PATH`, I'd like to type `. setE<TAB>`  which would expand to `. setEnv.sh` . Hope this makes it clear.